# Problem with sending a modified Gravity Forms through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have an unusual problem. I defined a three-page form in Gravity Forms ( multi-page ). All fields in the form are required. All embedded on a website with enabled AJAX option and works fine.

Unfortunately, I have to get a paginated view of the form in my project. However, in the desktop view> 768px, all fields must be on one page.

Therefore, I used the css code that hides the PREV and NEXT buttons in the desktop view. And I'm adding a class: display:block for hidden single form pages to be visible.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
# gform_next_button_1_5,
# gform_previous_button_1_7,
# gform_next_button_1_7,
# gform_previous_button_1 {
display: none! important;
}

# gform_page_1_1,
# gform_page_1_2,
# gform_page_1_3 {
display: block! important;
}

}
```

Unfortunately, in the mobile view everything works as I wrote correctly. In the desktop view all fields are visible, the PREV and NEXT buttons are hidden, but the SEND button does not work.

The easiest way would be to make two forms, but unfortunately it is impossible because the system will consist of more forms and it will complicate the matter.

Here is link for preview of those form: http://gravity.d-c.pl/test

Maybe someone managed to solve a similar problem, a request for help :)

Comment: Got a link to see the form or potential to put up a dummy page or form? Kind fo hard to debug and help without the code

Comment: Yes sure :) here is link http://gravity.d-c.pl/test/

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though this functionality is dependent on the user submitting the next button to trigger the progress of the multi-page form. Without it, the form will not progress and the submit button is disabled still.

It should possible to write some javascript or jQuery to detect when the user has filled in any answer on page 2 of the form, to submit the next button for them and move the form along, but hide that action when the user is selecting items on page 2 and page 3. Des that point you in the right direction or are you looking for an example?

Comment: Such a solution should probably work, but I would need a specific code because I don't feel like writing it myself. I thought you could somehow just unlock the submit button and validate poles in some way.

Comment: You would need specific code that is only applicable to your form. The fact that you say you do not want to write it yourself and you are looking for me to write it, makes me not interested in helping you any more. Sorry to be that way, but I am not going to do your work or job for you.

Comment: it's not about you writing the code for me. The point is that your idea is based on having the next button pressed with a script. Only how the script will know if the user has finished writing and checking the fields. Without a concrete example of a piece of code, I can't imagine it. Theory is one thing, but a working example is another.